# Hello, trying to figure out how to extract just the file path from this text

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

```
[[vfile:/path/to/fountain/file.fountain|This is a plot point]]
```

I've tried the following. It removes the front vfile section but leaves the `pipe(|)` and what follows.

```
sed -e 's/.*\[\[vfile:\(.*\)\|.*/\1/'
```

The output I want is just the file path to the fountain file.

Comment: Never mind I think I got it just removed the backlash before the pipe(|)

Comment: Well, simple `cut` commands are nice: `echo $string | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d\| -f1`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 sed -E 's#.*:(.*)\|.*$#\1#'
```

Demo:

```
$echo '[[vfile:/path/to/fountain/file.fountain|This is a plot point]]' |  sed -E 's#.*:(.*)\|.*$#\1#' 
/path/to/fountain/file.fountain
```